# How to update an entry in Contentful

Tags: android, contentful

I am not getting to update my entry, before I try to update, I unpublish the entry using `client.entries().async().unPublish(entry)`, and it works, but when I try to update using the code below, I receive the follow message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entry must have a space associated.`

What am I doing wrong?

```
 final CMAClient client =
                        new CMAClient
                                .Builder()
                                .setAccessToken(contentfulConnection.getCMA_TOKEN())
                                .build();
     final CMASystem sys = new CMASystem();

    sys.setId(entryID).setVersion(CurrentVersion);  

    CMAEntry entry;
    entry.setField("name", "en-US", "TEST").setSystem(sys); 
    entry.setSpaceId(SPACE_ID);
    entry.setID("entryID");     


    client.entries().async().update(entry, new CMACallback<CMAEntry>() {

                @Override protected void onSuccess(CMAEntry entry) {

                   // Successfully created a new entry.

                   new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("Contentful")                                                                                                                                                                                 
                   .setMessage("Creation of an entry was successful." +"\n\nResult: 
                   " + 
                   entry).show();                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }           }


@Override protected void onFailure(RuntimeException exception) {

    // An error occurred! Inform the user.

    new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)

    .setTitle("Contentful Error")

    .setMessage("Could not create an entry." +

   "\n\nReason: " + exception.toString())



       .show();

       System.out.println(exception.toString());


       super.onFailure(exception);
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                        );
```

Answer (score -3):

I am a maintainer of the Contentful Java SDK.

The recommended way of using the `update` method is to first fetch an item, change its data and then update it again.

If you follow this link [to our documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry), and select the `create/update an entry` button, you'll see a code snippets on how to update entries. Please select  `Android` platform to see it for Android.

I hope this helps you a bit further.